# Add event to created element

Tags: jquery

I am updating my code ... Most things are solve. A problem remains:

When I move mouse faster between elements (1 and 2) the tooltip does not show.

I think this happens because I have a delay on element mouse leave:

```
$this.mouseleave(function (e) {
  tooltip.timer = setTimeout(function () {
    $("." + options.class).detach();
  }, !options.mouse || options.static ? options.delay || 0 : 0);
}), // Mouse leave
```

I have it to allow the mouse to move over the tooltip for when there is a link in it.

The idea would be to cancel the hide delay when the mouse goes over another element.

The plugin can be tested in http://jsfiddle.net/mdmoura/RPUX6/

And the entire code is the following:

```
(function ($) {

  $.fn.Tooltip = function (options) {

    var defaults = {
      class: 'Tooltip',
      content: '',      
      delay: 120,
      mouse: false,
      offset: [0, -20],
      static: true,
      effect: function ($element, $tooltip) {
        $tooltip.fadeIn(200);
      }      
    };

    options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    $(this).each(function (e) {
      var $this = $(this);
      var tooltip = { timer: null, title: $this.attr('title') };

      $this.mouseenter(function (e) {

        var $tooltip =
          $("<div>")
          .attr("class", options.class)
          .html(options.content !== '' ? (typeof options.content === 'string' ? options.content : options.content($this, $tooltip)) : tooltip.title)
          .appendTo('body');

        $this.attr('title', '');

        var position = [0, 0];

        if (options.mouse) {
          position = [e.clientX + options.offset[0] + $(window).scrollLeft(), e.clientY + options.offset[1] + $(window).scrollTop()];
        } else {
          var coordinates = $this[0].getBoundingClientRect();       
          position = [
            (function () {
              if (options.offset[0] < 0)
                return coordinates.left - Math.abs(options.offset[0]) - $tooltip.outerWidth() + $(window).scrollLeft();
              else if (options.offset[0] === 0)
                return coordinates.left - (($tooltip.outerWidth() - $this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft();
              else
                return coordinates.left + $this.outerWidth() + options.offset[0] + $(window).scrollLeft();

            })(),
            (function () {
              if (options.offset[1] < 0)
                return coordinates.top - Math.abs(options.offset[1]) - $tooltip.outerHeight() + $(window).scrollTop();
              else if (options.offset[1] === 0)
                return coordinates.top - (($tooltip.outerHeight() - $this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop();
              else
                return coordinates.top + $this.outerHeight() + options.offset[1] + $(window).scrollTop();

            })()
          ];
        }

        $tooltip.css({ left: position[0] + 'px', top: position[1] + 'px' });

        options.effect($this, $tooltip.stop(true, true));

        $tooltip.mouseenter(function () {
          window.clearTimeout(tooltip.timer);
          tooltip.timer = null;
        }); // Tooltip enter

        $tooltip.mouseleave(function () {
          tooltip.timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $tooltip.remove();
          }, !options.mouse || options.static ? options.delay || 0 : 0);
        });

      }), // Mouse enter

      $this.mouseleave(function (e) {
        tooltip.timer = setTimeout(function () {
          $("." + options.class).remove();
        }, !options.mouse || options.static ? options.delay || 0 : 0);
      }), // Mouse leave  

      $this.mousemove(function (e) {
        if (options.mouse && !options.static) {
          $("." + options.class).css({ left: e.clientX + options.offset[0] + $(window).scrollLeft() + 'px', top: e.clientY + options.offset[1] + $(window).scrollTop() + 'px' });
        }
      }); // Mouse move
    }); // Each
  }; // Tooltip
})(jQuery); // JQuery
```

I am using timeouts to allow the mouse to move over the tooltip.

Does anyone knows how to solve the current problem?

Thank You!

Comment: i am not wrong,you needed like this right?http://designm.ag/previews/tooltip-menu/source/

Comment: Did you create this plugin? Also have you considered using [`jQuery UI's Tooltip`](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)?

Comment: Your codepen link seems to be broken.

Comment: Try hint.css and don't rely on javascript at all. http://kushagragour.in/lab/hint/

Comment: I just updated my code. Only one problem remaining. Does anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: Note : you modified your question so that it now becomes impossible to understand how the answers are related to this, or the initial question `Add event to created element`. Try to keep enough information to explain how it evolved from the starting point.

Comment: [edit] or split it in several questions

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try this plugin - [jQuery Powertip](http://stevenbenner.github.io/jquery-powertip/)

You can interact with the tool-tip with the `mouseOnToPopup` option.

```
$('#mouseon-examples div').powerTip({
    placement: 'e',
    mouseOnToPopup: true // <-- Important bit
});
```

"You can also fiddle with PowerTip on the official [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stevenbenner/2baqv/)"

Comment: Even if this is not a direct answer to the OP problem, I would recommend using an existing plugin rather than reinvent the wheel and struggle yet another time with all the corner cases.

Comment: I have been trying a few tooltip plugins but there is always something that I need to use in a different way ... This is why I decided to create my own. I just updated the code. There is only one problem remaining. Does anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this plugin?

Comment: @apaul34208: I am trying to have a tooltip plugin as flexible as possible in which I can control the code ...

Comment: @Shapper Have you considered modifying an existing tool tip plugin? You can always take one and change the script to meet your needs. There may be one out there that only needs a small modification. It will likely save you a lot of time and aggravation.

Comment: Yes, I have considered ... And in fact parts of my code reflect that. The main problem most of the tooltips with clear code don't allow the mouse to mover over the tooltip. The ones that allow usually have really long code ... What is frustrating is that I have my tooltip code almost working but I am not able to finish it ...

Answer (score 0):

Replace your mouseleave function with that:

```
    $(this).mouseout(function (e) {
       setTimeout(function(){
       $("#Tooltip").remove();
       }, 1000);
    }),
```

But after 1s, the problem will be the same: the tooltip will disappear.

Comment: @roasted Nope, they're not. `mouseout` bubbles, `mouseleave` doesn't.

Comment: @m_gol In fact, mouseout doesn't bubbles by default, mouseleave does. Thx for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

After create your Tooltip:

```
    $('#Tooltip').mouseenter(function(){
      $(this).addClass('active');
    });
     $('#Tooltip').mouseleave(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
          $("#Tooltip").remove();
        }, 1000);  
    });
```

When you leave the tooltip zone, check if the 'active' class exist.

```
  $(this).mouseout(function (e) {
    if($('#Tooltip').hasClass('active'))
    {
      setTimeout(function(){
        $("#Tooltip").remove();
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $this.mouseleave(function (e) {
    setTimeout(function(){ ...
```

Maybe you forgot some code in your post, but the id of the timeout is not stored anywhere so it cannot be cleared. You could write `timer = setTimeout(...`, where timer is defined as follows

```
 $(this).each(function () {     
   var $this = $(this),
       timer;
```

Then you can clear is easily with

```
 $tooltip.mouseenter(function (e) {
   clearTimeout(timer);
 });
```

And your mouseleave handler should be

```
 $tooltip.mouseleave(function (e) {
  $(this).remove(); //or $tooltip.remove();
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/RPUX6/76/

```
 $this.mouseleave(function (e) {
      $("." + options.class).fadeOut(500, function() {
          this.remove();
      });
 }), // Mouse leave
```

I verified that this does remove the tooltip.  I'm not sure why you say it doesn't.  Strange.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RPUX6/75/

Try this:  Instead of removing the tooltip, just use the fadeOut to give you time to hover over the tooltip.

Comment: That wouldn't do ... If you check the code I will be adding one Tooltip div every time I mouse over an element. I would like to use the same tooltip div.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RPUX6/76/  You can always add a remove() when the animation is completed like I did here.  Sorry but I don't understand your previous comment about using the same tooltip.  I'm not sure why you need to have `setTimeout()` to do a `remove()` when you can achieve the same effect with `fadeOut()`.

Comment: Your new code won't "work". It sill adds many tooltip divs. If you check with Firebug the tooltip div's are not being removed. That is what I meant with "The same tooltip". Maybe not the best expression. The reason why I have a Timeout is because I need to be able, when I want, to move the mouse over the tooltip so when there is a menu in it ...

Comment: Are you looking at the correct fiddle?  It does remove the tooltip.  And you can still mouseover the tooltip to stop it from being removed.

Comment: I am looking at this one: http://jsfiddle.net/RPUX6/76/. I opened Firebug and then moved the mouse over "01" and "02". Each time I move the mouse over the a link one <div class="Tooltip"> is added to html source. When I move out the div fades out but at the end is not removed from the source. So after a few hovers I get a lot of divs in the source. Are you checking with Firebug? I can send you a screenshot.

Comment: And by the way, you are using the fade out as a way to allow the user to move the mouse over the tooltip ... But it shouldn't be that way. There should be the delay to allow the user to move the mover over the tooltip ... And fade out only after that.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Well, I'm not sure how to fix your issue in that case.  Good luck!  If you decide to use Qtip2, I can help, I've implemented the same issue using that library.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, I support [apaul34208](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16108202/86072) in suggesting "use an already existing plugin, for which people have already encountered and thought about the corner cases". Maybe this particular plugin won't do, but given the amount of tooltips plugin, you should find your need.

That being said :

Your problem is that your function systematically calls `.remove()`, when it should do something like `check if I should remove the tooltip, if yes do so`.

```
function incrVisCounter($tooltip){
    var cnt = 1 + $tootltip.data('visCounter');
    $tootltip.data('visCounter', cnt);
}

function decrVisCounter($tooltip){
    setTimeout(function(){
        var cnt = $tootltip.data('visCounter') - 1;
        $tootltip.data('visCounter', cnt);
        if (cnt <= 0) {
            $tooltip.remove();
        }
    }, 300);
}


    $this.mouseenter(function (e) {
        displayTooltipIfNotShownAlready($this); //<- you will need to write some code here ...

        incrVisCounter( $('#tooltip') );
    });

    $this.mouseleave(function (e) {
        decrVisCounter( $('#tooltip') );
    });


    $tooltip.mouseenter(function (e) {
        incrVisCounter( $(this) );
    });

    $tooltip.mouseleave(function (e) {
        decrVisCounter( $(this) );
    });
```

---

`$('.'+options.class).remove()` will remove *any* tooltip on your page. You have to target only the specific one.

One suggestion :

[edit] don't forget the `var` keyword ...

```
 $this.mouseenter(function(){
     var $tooltip = ...

     $this.data('tooltip', $tooltip);
 });

 $this.mouseleave(function(){
     var $tooltip = $this.data('tooltip');
     setTimeout(function(){ $tooltip.remove() }, delay);
 });
```

Comment: Yes, there are a lit of tooltip plugins ... But there isn't any that really satisfy all the things I need. Parts of my code are based on what those plugins to ... I have only one problem left. I just updated my code. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/ is another tooltip plugin, with many (too many ?) bells and whistles.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem ... Too Many whistles. I want something simple, flexible in which I can control the code. If you check my code you can style the tooltip with CSS. And you can set its behavior with only a few properties. I've tried most plugins out there and, maybe because I will not use this only as a simple tooltip, I need to have more flexibility on how I use it ...

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do.

Listen for a mouseover/click event on the area you want to trigger the tooltip from.
That part you did.

On tooltip show bind a global event listener on the body. Listen for mousemove, then check if you inside the tooltip or the trigger element.

If you are not then hide the tooltip and remove the global even listener.

A bit of pseudo code

```
onShow: function(){
  $('body').off('mousemove');
  //might want to do _.debounce to make sure you dont trigger it to often
  $('body').on('mousemove', function(e){
     if(!$tooltip.has(e.target) && !$this.has(e.target)) {
       $tooltip.hide(); 
     }
  });
}

onHide: function(){
  //naturally you should be more careful with this 
  //and not just blindly remove all mousemose on the body
  //easy fixed by giving the event a unique id
  $('body').off('mousemove')
}
```